# Simplifying polygons without "trimming" them

Tags: qgis, polygon, simplify

I have a quite difficult issue: I need to simplify polygons, but without "trimming" them - no parts of polygon can be lost; furthermore, all holes in polygons should be filled (but this last is less important and can be done by hand). I presented an example of what I need - the brown polygon is original, and the red outline is desired extent.

There is a significant amount of similar questions on the StackExchange, but answers were not sufficient.

I use QGIS 2.18.3 and I made some trials using SimpliPy plugin - but results using tolerance: 10  are not so satisfactory. Second picture presents it: in some places work has been done well by the plugin, but some parts are excessively simplified. Also, there are parts that had not been simplified.

I wonder whether I should just try with SimpliPy settings and parameters - or should I look for another way (maybe GRASS / SAGA algorithms)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe are you looking for a _smoothing_ operation, instead?

Comment: With one exception this rule works: take three vertices and remove one in the middle of they make right triangle outside original. Simplify first with 0 offset to eliminate extra points if any on straight segments. Doable if you know how to work with geometries

Comment: Mapshaper does topological simplification https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/ , it's available via R (probably Python too somewhere): https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper